# Como embaralhar aleatoriamente um Array em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

Eu gostaria de ter os itens de um array embaralhados. Algo assim:

```
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [2,1,3,4]
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [3,1,2,4]
[1,2,3,4].scramble => [4,2,3,1]
```

e assim por diante, randomicamente. Como fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o método [sample](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sample) que você passa a quantidade que quer de retorno, ou ainda tem o shuffle, segue um exemplo:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

#shuffle
>> array.shuffle
=> [4, 1, 2, 3]

#sample
>> array.sample(array.length)
=> [3, 1, 2, 4]
>> array.sample(array.length)
=> [2, 4, 1, 3]
```

Espero ter ajudado :)